# Github Apps - Can you pull without cloning the repo with github apps?

Tags: github, github-app

I am using [Github Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#using-python) to grant different accesses to my organisation.

Everything works fine and I am able to clone and pull the repos.

However, I have a doubt:

If, in the past, I had cloned the Github repo **without Github Apps**, if I follow the authentication process, will I be able to pull the code once the permissions only go through Apps?

Due to certain limitations I can't create a test that allows me to be 100% sure of this behaviour.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Yes, you can pull with GitHub Apps, but keep in mind that the remote URL is not directly:

```
https://github.com/{your_user}/{repo_name}.git
```

Instead, it will contain **the token in the middle**:

```
https://x-access-token:{generated_token}@github.com/{your_user}/{repo_name}.git
```

That means that every time you want to pull, you need to reset the remote URL with the new token that you created (only if it expired, of course).

And then you will be able to pull.